# Cosmic censorship conjecture: Why naked singularities are expected not to exist?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, quantum-gravity, singularities, cosmic-censorship

According to wikipedia, the weak form of the [Cosmic Censorship Hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_censorship_hypothesis) says the following:

> Singularities [...] are typically hidden within event horizons, and therefore cannot be observed from the rest of spacetime. Singularities that are not so hidden are called naked. The weak cosmic censorship hypothesis [...] posits that no naked singularities exist in the universe.

The reason they point out, is that:

> Since the physical behavior of singularities is unknown, if singularities can be observed from the rest of spacetime, causality may break down, and physics may lose its predictive power. The issue cannot be avoided, since according to the Penrose–Hawking singularity theorems, singularities are inevitable in physically reasonable situations. [...]. Failure of the cosmic censorship hypothesis leads to the failure of determinism, because it is yet impossible to predict the behavior of spacetime in the causal future of a singularity.

It is almost as if it is saying that singularities are real physical entities that exists in the universe. Is this true? I thought it was a problem with the theory: whenever a theory says a singularity exists, then such a theory is wrong and if you want to investigate the proximity or even the singularity itself, a better theory is needed. In the case of a gravitational singularity, GR is insufficient/wrong to treat the phenomena this close to a singularity and should not be trusted, and, a better theory is needed (say.. quantum gravity).

But if it is just a theory problem, then whats the reasoning to prompt majority of scientists to believe in the cosmic censorship conjecture? What's the problem with naked singularities existing? Is it a theory problem, or do singularities with infinite densities really exist in our universe to justify this conjecture? Am I missing something?

Comment: @safesphere Hey.. I am just quoting wikipedia which said r=0 is a singularity that cannot be removed with a change of coordinates, and, its a point of infinite density. So.. I don't know, that's why I asked the question. I just wrote what wikipedia said.

Comment: @safesphere I apologize. You are right. I saw this in another wikipedia page, when I began to search about this. So it was in [Naked Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_singularity) where it says: "The theoretical existence of naked singularities is important because their existence would mean that it would be possible to observe the collapse of an object to infinite density".

Comment: @KID Page 59 in [Light Rays, Singularities, and All That](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03928) says: "by now reasonable evidence for cosmic censorship has come from the fact that **simulations** of black hole collisions... have not generated naked singularities." Also, that paper is a good review of the singularity theorems and how they're proven. It's mathematical, of course, because the singularity theorems are mathematical results. (It's *not* an introduction to general relativity. It assumes that its readers already know the basics of general relativity.)

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Thank you! I read the section about this, and it did help me to understand a few things! Though I wish it had elaborated more on these collision simulations. Like, were they just doing some collisions that might appear in the real world? Or, were they doing collisions with BHs of high charge, and/or rotation, to see if they get a naked singularity from merge? I guess I'll have to try to find collision data hehe. Thank you a lot for pointing out this to me! It helped! I also found this [very nice answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/31991/286441) because of this! Thanks!